# Health check failure with HTTP/2 in a ALB target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

Created a new ALB with HTTP/2 support and configuring the target group to use HTTP/2 as well. The goal was to make them compatible. However, I am currently facing health check failures when using HTTP/2 with the target group in the ALB. Interestingly, when I used the same container with a different target group, it was able to successfully pass data using the HTTP/1.1 protocol. Could you please help me understand why the health checks are failing in the HTTP/2 configuration?

Comment: You need to add more info to the question. What type of healthcheck have you configured. Is your target group configured with https andf what tls version you have configured ecc.

Comment: If it's https , you need to enable earlier version of tls as well and not only the latest.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.